# Operation not permitted turning off airplay mirroring

Tags: permission, airplay

I'm running the command

```
sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent
```

Because AirPlay mirroring is messing with one of my programs, but it tells me "Operation is Not Permitted". I'm the owner of this Mac and should definitely be permitted, some help please?

Comment: Do you have El Capitan? If so, did you turn of SIP?

Comment: Yeah I have El capitan, what's SIP? (I'm new to mac)

Comment: SIP (aka rootless) aims to stop you from doing what you're doing (as well as other applications). It stops anything from modifying System files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP). It stops anything from modifying System files.

Disabling SIP: (more info in [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/))

1. Enter **Recovery HD**
2. From the Utilities menu, select **Terminal**
3. Type in `csrutil disable`

Answer (score 1):

Turning Off Rootless System Integrity Protection in Mac OS X
Again, the vast majority of Mac users should not disable rootless. Disabling rootless is aimed exclusively at advanced Mac users. Do so at your own risk, this is not specifically recommended.

Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime, this will boot Mac OS X into Recovery Mode

When the “MacOS Utilities” / “OS X Utilities” screen appears, pull down the ‘Utilities’ menu at the top of the screen instead, and choose “Terminal”

Type the following command into the terminal then hit return:

```
csrutil disable
```

You’ll see a message saying that System Integrity Protection has been disabled and the Mac needs to restart for changes to take effect.

Then execute `reboot` and the Mac will then reboot itself automatically, just let it boot up as normal

http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

**Hint**: If it does not work on the first time, then close the terminal and reboot, then try again.

### WARNING: You should enable it again once you are done, otherwise you are opening a big security hole.

Enable it with `csrutil enable`