# New MacBook Air - update installation failed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update

I have a new MacBook Air. I just bought it and first started it. I try to update it to the latest version, but I get `Installation failed`. I try to install macOS 10.14.5.

Where are the updates stored after they are downloaded? Maybe it works if I delete it and download the update again?

I am totally new to macOS any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is current version ?

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Did you try installing from App Store?

Comment: You can get the downloadable Combo Updater to 10.14.5 [at this link](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2000?locale=en_US). Make sure you do a full backup before you run any updates.

Comment: Although I recommend waiting for a few days and getting yourself familiar to the file structure and usage of Mac as well as appleID . It can get tough to come out a problem in case you run into trouble while updating. @Black

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I can't wait. I only bought it to install Xcode so I can develop apps for iOS, but I need at least version macOS 10.14.3 to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP). Just follow this answer:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361046/333653

Then I had to open a terminal and delete all folders in `/Library/Updates` with `sudo rm -Rf` e.g. `sudo rm -Rf 041-57076`. These are the update files, I need to delete them because they are corrupted because of poor internet connection.

Now I triggered the update again, it began to download the update again and now it works :)

If it does still fail, then try this procedure again, but connect via cable not via Wifi.

Comment: +1 for documenting where internally these are stored. I normally just boot to internet recovery to get a fresh copy of everything.

Comment: You **do not** need to disable **System Integrity Protection** (SIP). Simply boot to the Recovery HD and delete it from Terminal there and no need to use `sudo` as it's already a root shell. Then reboot the Mac. BTW You do need to delete it from e.g., `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Updates` when done from the Recovery HD.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was a missing `/private/tmp` directory. I recreated it like this:

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Afterwards the installation went through successfully.