# Mac OS Update to 10.14.5 error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

The error:

[image]

[image]

Console log:

```
 2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: SUBridgeOSUpdateManager: bridgeOS update prepare for 041-57074 failed: Error Domain=BOSErrorDomain Code=111 "An error occurred extracting the update or brain package." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred extracting the update or brain package., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9c071cd9a0 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive verify failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Library/Updates/041-57074/BridgeOSUpdateCustomer.pkg#Payload, NSFileOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=23313017, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777221, NSFileSize=327028014, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=root, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileCreationDate=2019-05-21 02:38:18 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileExtendedAttributes={
            "com.apple.quarantine" = <30303836 3b356365 33363731 393b3b>;
        }, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=wheel, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2019-05-22 02:42:43 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive verify failed}}}
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: Changing status (foreground bridgeOS prepare failed) for key 041-57074 from "preparing bridgeOS update" to "download error"
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: Stopping transaction with ID [0x6]
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: SoftwareUpdate: Removed foreground transaction [0x6]
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: Running session-idle tasks.
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 softwareupdated[525]: Checking for inapplicable local products remaining on disk for cleanup
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[875]: SUAppStoreUpdateController: status for 041-57074: 041-57074 (a=0x3): download error (2806700848 of 2806700848) 80.0% 1.0s (error: Error Domain=SUErrorDomain Code=602 "An error occurred installing the update." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc7500218f0 {Error Domain=BOSErrorDomain Code=111 "An error occurred extracting the update or brain package." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred extracting the update or brain package., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc750038cd0 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive verify failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Library/Updates/041-57074/BridgeOSUpdateCustomer.pkg#Payload, NSFileOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=23313017, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777221, NSFileSize=327028014, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=root, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileCreationDate=2019-05-21 02:38:18 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileExtendedAttributes={
            "com.apple.quarantine" = <30303836 3b356365 33363731 393b3b>;
        }, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=wheel, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2019-05-22 02:42:43 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive verify failed}}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=You can try again to complete the installation., NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred installing the update.})
    2019-06-12 11:21:10+08 Williams-MacBook-Pro-6 system_installd[896]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=525, uid=200 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated)
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360997/new-macbook-air-update-installation-failed#comment478278_360997... Does this help? Also please check in "Advanced " if automatic download is turned on or not. That helps isolating download from updating.

Comment: Yes, it works. Tried to delete `/Library/Updates` didn't a success, know SIP needs to be disabled. thanks!@ankiiiiiii

Comment: As far as I understood by communications in the linked questions, entering in recovery mode nullifies the disabling of System integrity protection. So please **do not** disable it causally.

Comment: If you don't disable it you can't find that path. `Volume` path only contains some folder like `Mac Base OS`. I think it's fine you can enable it again.

Answer (score 2):

The error could be the download progress was interrupted.

The macOS updated files are located in `/Library/Updates`, needs to clean up that folder. You can't simply delete it.

By the following steps:

1. Restart your mac, press `Command + R`, then enter into Recovery HD.
2. Choose utility menu, select `Terminal`.
3. `csrutil disable` to disable SIP.
4. `reboot`.
5. Delete the files in folder `/Library/Updates`.
6. Enter Recovery HD again, and input `csrutil enable` in `Terminal`.
7. `reboot`.
8. Check the update should work.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362204/8948) will work, but unnecessarily disables System Integrity Protection (SIP).

The error I could see when opening Console while the update was running was:

```
Error occurred during download: Error Domain=SUErrorDomain Code=602 "An error occurred installing the update." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred installing the update., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=You can try again to complete the installation., 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x600001a50ff0 {Error Domain=BOSErrorDomain Code=111 "An error occurred extracting the update or brain package." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred extracting the update or brain package., 
    NSUnderlyingError=0x600001a50360 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive verify failed" 
      UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Library/Updates/061-64339/BridgeOSUpdateCustomer.pkg#Payload, NSFileOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=93069049, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777220, NSFileSize=449515770, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=root, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileCreationDate=2020-02-11 22:07:02 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileExtendedAttributes={"com.apple.quarantine" = <30303836 3b356534 33323538 363b3b>;
}, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=wheel, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2020-02-11 22:08:17 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive verify failed}}}}}
```

Looking at the error, you can see the corrupted file is at `/Library/Updates/061-64339/BridgeOSUpdateCustomer.pkg#Payload`. SIP prevents modification to system folders, including `/Library/Updates`. You need to boot into recovery mode, or disable SIP to delete these files so they can be re-downloaded.

To remove corrupted update files without disabling SIP:

1. Restart your Mac, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to enter recovery mode while it is starting
2. Once recovery mode has booted, you should see this:

   [image: macOS recovery mode utilities]
3. Open Disk Utility
4. Make sure that your main disk is mounted. In my case it is called "Macintosh HD", and was unmounted. If it's not mounted, click Mount, and enter your disk password if you have one. This may take a few moments.
5. Once you've mounted your disk, close Disk Utility and open Utilities > Terminal (see the image above).
6. You need to delete the corrupted update from your disk, not from the recovery partition. If you go to `/Library`, you will see the recovery partition Library folder, not the one for your main system. You need to go to `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Updates`.
7. Into the terminal enter:

   ```
   -bash-3.2# cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Updates
   -bash-3.2# ls
   061-64339       ProductMetadata.plist
   PPDVersions.plist   index.plist
   -bash-3.2# rm -rf 061-64339/
   ```
8. Quit Terminal and reboot your Mac
9. Open System Preferences > Software Update, and try to update again